# How to apply filters dynamically in nicolaskruchten pivottable.js

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am using nicolaskruchten pivottable, for displaying my data using:

```
$('#output').pivot([
    {country: "USA", city: "Boston"},
    {country: "USA", city: "NYC"},
    {country: "UK", city: "London"},
],
{
    rows: ["country"],
    cols: ["city"]
});
```

Its displaying table properly but now I want to filter my data dynamically in the table.

One of the way is, to filter my available data and redraw pivot table with filter data. 
I want to know if there is any inbuilt filter method available.

There is an provision for a filter object in the options array of pivot(input [,options]) method but not able to find any example to implement.

If anyone can suggest me how to proceed further ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must re-render the table every time you filter. You can pass a `filter` attribute which is a function that takes a row as a parameter and returns a boolean. See https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters#pivotinput-options

I should add that in general, you should file a Github Issue to get help with this library, rather than asking a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @nicolaskruchten, for your assistance and time it helped me and worked for me.
Below is the way i have done:
`var filterBy={filterCol:"country",filterValue:["USA"]};
optObject['filter']=function(rowObj){
if(filterBy.filterValue.indexOf(rowObj[filterBy.filterCol])>-1) return true;
else return false;
};`

Comment: @Mayur: Could you please post your comment as an answer so we may find it useful. Thanks.

Comment: @MohamedThaufee I have addedd as now answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way i have done it. and it solved my query.

```
 var filterBy={filterCol:"country",filterValue:["USA"]};

    optObject['filter']=function(rowObj){ 
if(filterBy.filterValue.indexOf(rowObj[filterBy.filterCol])>‌​-1) return true; 
else return false; 
};
```

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle. Could you please edit code and apply your filters ? JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w86bgq9o/474/

Answer (score -1):

I used search/select box to filter data dynamically. 
Data to the filter is fed dynamically from Back-end.

In index.html:

--------------  //search-select box 1
--------------  //search-select box 2 ...

==============  //pivot table

You can actually pass a filter attribute. But this will be a better implementation in the memory perspective.

By implementing a default set of records to be displayed, you can limit the data that is getting loaded to Front-end using dynamic filters.

Comment: I am downvoting it as the answer is not clear and might even add more confusion. No Fiddler or sample code.